# Setting subnet mask In vagrant for public network

Tags: networking, ip, vagrant, public, subnet

I need to run some services in vagrant, so that its accessible in browser. By giving network type as `public_network` in Vagrantfile, I am getting a vagrant Ip (10.251.70.201).

Now, using this vagrant Ip am able to get these service in other device's browser (which are in the same network: 10.251.70.*). Now I need to expand the visibility of the vagrant Ip in other networks (like 10.251.*.*). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using Virtualbox provider. As an example:

```
 config.vm.network "public_network", :netmask => "255.255.0.0"
```

Comment: That I tried, but I wont work. From ifconfig command, the mask is 255.255.255.0 itself in vagrant

Comment: If you have a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 you can't access from 10.251.70.* to 10.251.*.* without a static route. But that's not a Vagrant related issue, you have to fix your network config.

Answer (score 2):

This is example of using Virtualbox provider for Vagrant version 2 config file:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "eth0", ip:"192.168.1.20", netmask:"255.255.0.0"
```